# Building jQuery fails to minify with error "/bin/sh: line 0: test: /usr/bin/node: binary operator expected", but NodeJS is installed at /usr/bin/node

Tags: jquery, node.js, makefile

I'm trying to [build jQuery from source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/README.md#how-to-build-your-own-jquery), and I'm running into an odd problem.

I can build the un-minified version, but when it tries to minify the js file, I get the following errors:

```
> make
...
Building ./dist/jquery.js
/bin/sh: line 0: test: /usr/bin/node: binary operator expected
You must have NodeJS installed in order to minify jQuery.
/bin/sh: line 0: test: /usr/bin/node: binary operator expected
You must have NodeJS installed in order to test jQuery against JSHint.
/bin/sh: line 0: test: /usr/bin/node: binary operator expected
You must have NodeJS installed in order to size jQuery.
```

What's weird, though, is that NodeJS **is** installed at `/usr/bin/node`.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out one of the lines that generates the error:

```
@@if test ! -z ${JS_ENGINE}; then \
```

Here's where `${JS_ENGINE}` is defined at the top of `Makefile`:

```
JS_ENGINE ?= `which node nodejs 2>/dev/null`
```

If I run that command on my system, here's what I get:

```
> which node nodejs 2>/dev/null
/usr/bin/node
/usr/bin/nodejs
```

Notice that the output contains 2 lines, not 1!

To fix this, override the `${JS_ENGINE}` property when you invoke `make` like so:

```
make JS_ENGINE=`which node nodejs 2>/dev/null | head -n 1`
```

Comment: Why not just export JS_ENGINE="node"